# How can I watch for state of data in redux container, when I want to sort or filter it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

### I have some data as array of objects. I'd sort or filter it with redux and react-redux.

*My initial state*:

```js
let initialState = {
  persons:[],
  active:0,
  loading:false,
  filter:"",
  field:"name",
  increase:true
}
```

As the filtration and sorting are deal for UI, I try to implement it in container(smart component).
I was reading docs of redux,react-redux for last few days and got that I need to use **reselect**. So, I created two selectors: **sortData** that stores latest sorted array of data, and **filterData** that stores latest filtered array of data

*arguments of selectors - the field for selector watching*:

```js
let getPersons = (state) => state.persons
let getFilter = (state) => state.filter
let getField = (state) => state.field
let getIncrease = (state) => state.increase
```

*sortData*:

```js
let sortData = createSelector(
  [getPersons, getField,getIncrease],
  (persons,field,increase) =>  {
    console.log("SORT");
    let sortarr = persons.slice(0);
    return sortarr.sort((a , b) => {
      if (a[field] > b[field])  return increase ?  1: -1
      if (a[field] < b[field])  return increase ? -1:1
      return 0
    })
  })
```

*filterData*:

```js
let filterData = createSelector(
  [sortData,getFilter],
  (persons,filter) => {
    return persons.filter( p =>{
      console.log("FILTER");
      return p.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    })
  },
)
```

As you can see above, my selector **filterData** depends on **sortData** but not on the contrary. 
When I filterData It calls only filter calculation but when I try to sort data It calls both sort and filter.

My *mapStateToProps*:

```js
let mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  let modernState = filterData(state)
  return {
      activePerson:modernState[state.active],
      persons:modernState,
      loading:state.loading,
      active:state.active
    }
}
```

**When I click "filter data" I want to filter latest sorted array, and when I click "sort data" I want to sort latest filtered array.** 
My questions:

1. How can I make this functionality without re-calculation?
2. Can I implement it without **reselect**?

P.S. I read examples by Dan Abramov but, unfortunately, I cannot have applied it for solution of my task.
More code:[enter link description here](https://github.com/maximusnikulin/SearchAndFilter/blob/master/js/containers/PersonsBoard.js#L17)

Comment: can you show the rest of the code in storeData? i.e What does storeData look like, the one that you are passing into filterData....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following, it would be fine to keep it in one file then use this as your selector when you connect the component

```
// yourComponentSelector.js

let getPersons = (state) => state.persons
let getFilter = (state) => state.filter
let getField = (state) => state.field
let getIncrease = (state) => state.increase
let getLoading = (state) => state.loading
let getActive = (state) => state.active

let sortData = createSelector(
  [getPersons, getField,getIncrease],
  (persons,field,increase) =>  {
    console.log("SORT");
    let sortarr = persons.slice(0);
    return sortarr.sort((a , b) => {
      if (a[field] > b[field])  return increase ?  1: -1
      if (a[field] < b[field])  return increase ? -1:1
      return 0
    })
  })

function filterData(data, filter) {
   return data.filter(p => {
       console.log("FILTER");
       return p.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1
   });
}

let filterDataSelector = createSelector(
   [sortData, filter],
   (persons, filter) => {
      return filterData(persons, filter)
   })

export const yourComponentSelector = createSelector(
  [filterDataSelector,
   getLoading,
   getActive
  ],
  (persons, loading, active) => {
    return {
       persons: persons,
       activePerson: persons[active],
       loading: loading,
       active: active
    }
  },
)
```

#### Then in your component

```
   import { yourComponentSelector } from './yourComponentSelector.js';

   // instead of using your mapStatToProps function you can now use the selector

   export default connect(yourComponentSelector)(yourComponent);
```

#### So in short

If you need to sort the data its going to re-calculate filteredData because sortData has changed and you want to filter the most recent sorted data, if your filter changes it's going to re-calculation filterData but not sortData. The way re-select works is that it will only recalculate the state if one of the arguments you pass to createSelector has changed so just be mindful of that when building selectors.

Comment: Array "persons" are static data. So when I click sort data, "SORT" and "FILTER" implement together, but it needs only "SORT" of them. Could you take a look at my mapStateToProps function? I have also added my sortData function.

Comment: Unfortunately, result is same =( I assume that it needs to use memoiztion of react-redux: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/695328081398120450

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong inputs to your selectors, so `filterData` should be an input to `sortData` and `getPersons` should be an input to `filterData`:

```
let sortData = createSelector(
  [filterDataSelector, getField, getIncrease],
  (persons,field,increase) =>  {
    console.log("SORT");
    let sortarr = persons.slice(0);
    return sortarr.sort((a , b) => {
      if (a[field] > b[field])  return increase ?  1: -1
      if (a[field] < b[field])  return increase ? -1:1
      return 0
    })
  })

function filterData(data, filter) {
   return data.filter(p => {
       console.log("FILTER");
       return p.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1
   });
}

let filterDataSelector = createSelector(
   [getPersons, filter],
   (persons, filter) => {
      return filterData(persons, filter)
})

export const yourComponentSelector = createSelector(
  [sortData,
   getLoading,
   getActive
  ],
  (persons, loading, active) => {
    return {
       persons: persons,
       activePerson: persons[active],
       loading: loading,
       active: active
    }
  },
)
```